# Funções do PHP adaptadas ao MySQL

Tags: php, mysql

Ao tentar otimizar algumas *queries* para não depender do PHP para fazer algo que poderia vir pronto do banco de dados, eu estava tentando adaptar as duas rotinas abaixo em forma de *functions* do MySQL:

```
function encode( $input, $index ) {

    $base    = strlen( $index );
    $input  += pow( $base, 4 );
    $output  = '';

    for( $i = floor( log( $input, $base ) ); $i >= 0; $i-- ) {

        $bcp     = bcpow( $base, $i );
        $start   = floor( $input / $bcp ) % $base;
        $output .= substr( $index, $start, 1 );
        $input   = $input - ( $start * $bcp );
    }

    return $output;
}
```

E:

```
function decode( $input, $index ) {

    $base   = strlen( $index );
    $output = 0;
    $length = strlen( $input ) - 1;

    for( $i = 0; $i <= $length; $i++ ) {

        $bcpow   =  bcpow( $base, $length - $i );

        $output += strpos( $index, substr( $input, $i, 1 ) ) * $bcpow;
    }

    $output -= pow( $base, 4 );

    $output = sprintf( '%F', $output );
    $output = substr( $output, 0, strpos( $output, '.' ) );

    return (int) $output;
}
```

São funções que codificam um *integer* em uma *string* e vice-versa, um  *AlphaID*, quase como o do Youtube.

Como até o presente momento eu nunca havia criado uma *function* do MySQL, li o manual (que não é exatamente amigável) e cheguei, pelo menos quanto a *function* de codificação, nisso:

```
DROP FUNCTION IF EXISTS ENCODE_ALPHAID;

DELIMITER $$

CREATE FUNCTION ENCODE_ALPHAID( input integer ) RETURNS CHAR( 6 ) DETERMINISTIC

BEGIN

    DECLARE output CHAR( 6 );

    DECLARE letters CHAR( 62 );
    DECLARE base TINYINT( 2 );

    DECLARE iterator TINYINT( 2 );
    DECLARE bcp CHAR( 9 );
    DECLARE start TINYINT( 2 );

    SET output   = '';

    SET letters  = 'abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz0123456789ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ';

    SET base     = CHAR_LENGTH( letters );
    SET input    = input + POW( base, 4 );

    SET iterator = FLOOR( LOG( base, input ) );

    ENCODING: LOOP

        SET bcp      = POW( base, iterator );
        SET start    = FLOOR( input / bcp ) % base + 1;

        SET output   = CONCAT( output, SUBSTR( letters, start, 1 ) );

        SET input    = input - ( start * bcp );

        SET iterator = iterator-1;

        IF iterator < 0 THEN LEAVE ENCODING; END IF;

    END LOOP ENCODING;

    RETURN output;

END $$

DELIMITER ;
```

A rotina foi criada com sucesso mas tem alguns problemas:

1. A rotina original, em PHP, codifica corretamente até o valor máximo possível, descrito pela constante **PHP_INT_MAX** (2147483647), porém a adptação para o MySQL não. Em algum momento, que não pude depurar a fundo, a codificação aparentemente pára, e as *queries* não retornam dados.
2. Até onde a codificação funciona, ela sempre atua "um pra frente".Por exemplo, codficar o inteiro **2**, ao invés de retornar o esperado **baaac** está retornando **baaad**

Já quanto à função de decodificação:

```
DROP FUNCTION IF EXISTS DECODE_ALPHAID;

DELIMITER $$

CREATE FUNCTION DECODE_ALPHAID( input integer ) RETURNS INTEGER( 10 ) DETERMINISTIC

BEGIN

    DECLARE output INT( 10 );

    DECLARE letters CHAR( 62 );
    DECLARE base TINYINT( 1 );
    DECLARE length TINYINT( 1 );

    DECLARE iterator TINYINT( 1 );
    DECLARE bcp CHAR( 9 );
    DECLARE dot CHAR( 1 );

    SET output   = 0;

    SET letters  = 'abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz0123456789ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ';

    SET base     = CHAR_LENGTH( letters );
    SET length   = CHAR_LENGTH( input ) - 1;

    SET iterator = 0;
    SET dot = '.';

    ENCODING: LOOP

        SET bcp      = POW( base, length - iterator );

        SET output   = output + LOCATE( SUBSTR( input, iterator, 1 ), letters ) * bcp;

        SET iterator = iterator+1;

        IF iterator <= length THEN LEAVE ENCODING; END IF;

    END LOOP ENCODING;

    SET output = ( output - POW( base, 4 ) ) + 0.0;

    SET output = SUBSTR( output, 0, LOCATE( dot, output ) );

    RETURN output;

END $$

DELIMITER ;
```

Sequer decodifica e, acredito eu, seja pela forma a qual o [autor original](https://github.com/poops/php-classes/blob/master/AlphaId.php) das funções em PHP operou os resultados, formatando o cálculo matemático para *float*, operando como *string* e convertendo de volta pra *integer* que me faltou conhecimento em adaptar corretamente.

Comment: Mesmo que a necessidade real do projeto seja ter uma representação textual única do ID do registro, fazendo diretamente pelo MySQL posso me valer de tipos maiores, como o BIGINT, e ter 9,223,372,036,854,775,807 combinações, uma para cada registro.

Comment: Faltou os caracteres: `~!@$*()-_+=|,.`, não seria isso o problema?

Comment: Não seria melhor usar o [próprio método do MySQL](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/encryption-functions.html#function_encrypt) para isso? Ou [esse](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/encryption-functions.html#function_encode).

Comment: Não sabia que haviam funções nativas para isso. Eu poderia então, nesse caso, fazer `ENCRYPT( \`c\`.\`cid\`, 'abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz0123456789ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ' )`, porque está retornando `NULL`. E usando AES_ENCRYPT, já que a outra está depreciada eu não consigo ver o que retorna pois aparece *Binary* na GUI que eu uso

Comment: @BrunoAugusto base64 nao serve pro que  vc quer (tem do Mysql 5.6 em diante)? Ou é pra compatibilizar com algo já existente?

Comment: Não, não é pra manter compatibilidade com nada, é apenas uma característica do projeto na qual uma determinada coisa, bem estrutura já, a qual múltiplos usuários podem ter múltiplas "cópias", precisam obrigatoriamente ter uma representação textual (letras e números apenas). O mais plausível pra mim até o momento que decidi portar essas funções, era um *AlphaID* sob a chave-primária

Answer (score 1):

Para gravar você pode fazer o seguinte:

```
INSERT INTO tabela (id, content)
VALUES (1, AES_ENCRYPT('seu conteúdo aqui', 'senha123_hash'));
```

E depois recuperar assim:

```
SELECT CAST(AES_DECRYPT(content, 'senha123_hash') as CHAR) AS content_decrypted,
       content as content_encrypt
FROM tabela WHERE id=1;
```

Neste caso, de precisar gerar uma senha **alpha_id** você grava os dois, o conteúdo encriptado e a senha encriptada neste formato, e depois na consulta você utiliza a o hash **alpha_id** para buscar o conteúdo, exemplo:

```
INSERT INTO tabela (id_tst, content, alpha_id)
VALUES (6, AES_ENCRYPT('seu conteúdo aqui', SHA2(MD5('senha123_hash'),512)),SHA2(MD5('senha123_hash'),512));

SELECT CAST(AES_DECRYPT(content, SHA2(MD5('senha123_hash'),512)  ) as CHAR) AS content_decrypted,
       content as content_encrypt,
       alpha_id
FROM tabela WHERE alpha_id='ea921eccc6b836f894710943da3b5a9ff546cb775e4d7c9e00a892d313165967e8a7eb2ebe105c8f1a0fcc74e47a77a2e901c8b450baa8de5f4a5a13b83c4415';
```

Ou com 256:

```
 INSERT INTO tabela (id_tst, content, alpha_id)
 VALUES (6, AES_ENCRYPT('seu conteúdo aqui', SHA2(MD5('senha123_hash'),256)),SHA2(MD5('senha123_hash'),256));

 SELECT CAST(AES_DECRYPT(content, SHA2(MD5('senha123_hash'),256)  ) as CHAR) AS content_decrypted,
        content as content_encrypt,
        alpha_id
 FROM tabela WHERE alpha_id='069b8392f647410845de6b9d796b6c2e0a628194682bb2c3e5ec8b978e5787c9';
```

Se você não faz questão de encriptar o seu conteúdo no banco, também dá para gerar um alpha_id, apenas convertendo a saída para o hash:

```
SELECT content, CONCAT(CAST(content as CHAR), SHA2(id, 256)) AS alpha_id
FROM tabela WHERE id=1
```

Comment: Mas nesse caso eu estaria decodificando antes de exibir e a intenção solucionável pela "técnica" do *AlphaID* é justamente mostrar codiicado numa seqüência de apenas letras e números

Comment: Você pode codificar por um tipo de `hash` que deseja alpha numerico .

Comment: Experimentei o SHA1() e todas as combinações do SHA2() mas por serem mais para criptografia o comprimento ficou meio longo e exibir isso seria complicado. Com *AlphaID*, mesmo um número grande como um integer 32bits fica bem pequeno

Comment: MD5 é 32, mas você pode quebrar essa string no banco, é só limitar o varchar(tamanho)

Comment: Porque no final, o que te interessa é ter uma ID alpha_id certo, que traga um conteúdo secreto. e no lugar da senha, você coloca o conteúdo mesmo, ou a ID do registro + algumas palavras secretas.

Comment: Só que se que quebrar um hash aumenta consideravelmente o risco de colisão

Comment: quebra e concatena com a id. Nunca mais vai ter colisão.

Comment: exemplo: 6c2e0a628194682bb2c3e5ec8b978e5787c9**2**. sendo 2 a id