# Como trabalhar com AES_ENCRYPT e AES_DECRYPT

Tags: mysql

Estou com problemas para criptografar e descriptografar dados. 
Usei o seguinte insert direto no mysql

```
insert into interditado (usuario_id, nome, data_cadastro) values (1, AES_ENCRYPT('Zé da Silva','MIICeQIBADANBgkqhkiG9w0BAQEFAASC') , sysdate());
```

Comment: Versão MySQL 5.1.11
Será que isso tem a ver? Vou atualiza minha base de dados.

Comment: Dê uma olhada [nessa minha resposta](http://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/140690/fun%C3%A7%C3%B5es-do-php-adaptadas-ao-mysql/140755#140755)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Resolvi.
**A Criptografia está disponível a parti da versão 4.0.2.**
Para trabalhar com criptografia deve-se alterar o **Charset** da coluna para **latim1** e **Collate** para **latin1_general_ci.**