# como trabalhar com aes_decrypt no symfony 3

Tags: php, symfony

Eu tenho um banco de dados que é criptografado por outro sistema e eu preciso descriptografar os dados para exibição no sistema feito em symfony 3.
Eu tenho a chave de descriptografia e preciso fazer isso. Eu tenho pouca experiência no Symfony.
Como eu devo fazer isso? Seria no Entity ou no Controller?

Comment: Olha [essa resposta](http://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/140690/fun%C3%A7%C3%B5es-do-php-adaptadas-ao-mysql/140755#140755)

Comment: @IvanFerrer, pode me ajudar, por favor.

Comment: Acredito que nenhum e nem outro. Você pode fazer isso como um service, model ou filter. Depende do que você está fazendo. A função do controller é só true / false para acionar métodos. A da entity, já tem mais a ver com a entidade que você está tratando. Se seu método pertence a entidade, então seria dentro dela.

Comment: @IvanFerrer.
Eu tentei algum assim mas não tenho nem ideia de como fazer isso.
`'/**
     * Get nomePaiDecrypt  
     * @param string $nome, $chave  
     * @return string  
     */  
    public function getNomeDecrypt($chave, $nome)  
    {  
        $chave = 'MIICeQIBADANBgkqhkiG9w0BAQEFAASC';  
        $nome = $this->nome;  
        return CRYPT_EXT_DES($nome, $chave);  
    }`'

Comment: Olhe na resposta que publiquei.

Comment: Onde? Não entendi. Sobre o fato de usar entity ou controller?
Desculpa mas eu não tenho experiência no symfony.
A função está correta?

Comment: Na outra pergunta.

Comment: Pode postar o link? Não estou achando.

Comment: Cara.
Sua outra pergunta é uma resposta SQL. O que eu preciso é de como fica isso no symfony.
Grato.

Comment: você está usando doctrine, ou dql? Dá uma [olhada aqui](http://symfony.com/legacy/doc/more-with-symfony/1_4/pt/08-advanced-doctrine-usage)

Comment: Ou [Annotations](http://symfony.com/blog/symfony2-annotations-gets-better)?

Comment: Sua pergunta, não contém informações suficientes para uma resposta ao que você pretende. O SQL, é a resposta à questão de como utilizar o `aes_decrypt`, como introduzir isso, depende de como você está fazendo uso da conexão.

Comment: está usando ORM?

Comment: Sim, @IvanFerrer.
Symfony envolve os seus recursos.

Comment: Ok, já é o primeiro passo para que alguém responda sua dúvida, porém, é melhor você editar sua pergunta e acrescentar: 1. o método do controller que irá chamar essa requisição; 2. a sua classe Entity. 3. o tipo de query que você pretende executar no seu banco.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Resolvido ao seguir o passo-a-passo desse link.
https://github.com/ambta/DoctrineEncryptBundle/blob/master/Resources/doc/installation.md